# How to change background color of a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my course I am making a memory card game. All I want to do here is to change the background color of a div (that has been created in Javascript) when clicked. When the div is clicked, the background color should change to its class name. I included my entire code for your reference, but the part I'm having issues with is the function handleCardClick(event). What am I doing wrong with
(event.target.style.background-color = selectedColor)?

I'm sure it is a simple fix, but any help is appreciated. Love this community!

```js
const gameContainer = document.getElementById("game");

const COLORS = [
  "red",
  "blue",
  "green",
  "orange",
  "purple",
  "red",
  "blue",
  "green",
  "orange",
  "purple"
];


// here is a helper function to shuffle an array
// it returns the same array with values shuffled
// it is based on an algorithm called Fisher Yates if you want ot research more
function shuffle(array) {
  let counter = array.length;

  // While there are elements in the array
  while (counter > 0) {
    // Pick a random index
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

    // Decrease counter by 1
    counter--;

    // And swap the last element with it
    let temp = array[counter];
    array[counter] = array[index];
    array[index] = temp;
  }

  return array;
}

let shuffledColors = shuffle(COLORS);

// this function loops over the array of colors
// it creates a new div and gives it a class with the value of the color
// it also adds an event listener for a click for each card
function createDivsForColors(colorArray) {
  for (let color of colorArray) {
    // create a new div
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    // give it a class attribute for the value we are looping over
    newDiv.classList.add(color);

    // call a function handleCardClick when a div is clicked on
    newDiv.addEventListener("click", handleCardClick);

    // append the div to the element with an id of game
    gameContainer.append(newDiv);
  }
}

// TODO: Implement this function!
function handleCardClick(event) {
  // you can use event.target to see which element was clicked
  let selectedColor = event.target.className;
  event.target.style.background-color = selectedColor;

  }

// when the DOM loads
createDivsForColors(shuffledColors);
```

```css
#game div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 15%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Memory Game!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Memory Game!</h1>
    <div id="game">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check your console log and address the line it says it had an issue with.

There is no such thing as **style.background-color**, it is **style.backgroundColor**

Change;

```
event.target.style.background-color = selectedColor;
```

to be;

```
event.target.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
```

Working Snippet:

```js
const gameContainer = document.getElementById("game");

const COLORS = [
  "red",
  "blue",
  "green",
  "orange",
  "purple",
  "red",
  "blue",
  "green",
  "orange",
  "purple"
];


// here is a helper function to shuffle an array
// it returns the same array with values shuffled
// it is based on an algorithm called Fisher Yates if you want ot research more
function shuffle(array) {
  let counter = array.length;

  // While there are elements in the array
  while (counter > 0) {
    // Pick a random index
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

    // Decrease counter by 1
    counter--;

    // And swap the last element with it
    let temp = array[counter];
    array[counter] = array[index];
    array[index] = temp;
  }

  return array;
}

let shuffledColors = shuffle(COLORS);

// this function loops over the array of colors
// it creates a new div and gives it a class with the value of the color
// it also adds an event listener for a click for each card
function createDivsForColors(colorArray) {
  for (let color of colorArray) {
    // create a new div
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    // give it a class attribute for the value we are looping over
    newDiv.classList.add(color);

    // call a function handleCardClick when a div is clicked on
    newDiv.addEventListener("click", handleCardClick);

    // append the div to the element with an id of game
    gameContainer.append(newDiv);
  }
}

// TODO: Implement this function!
function handleCardClick(event) {
  // you can use event.target to see which element was clicked
  let selectedColor = event.target.className;
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;

  }

// when the DOM loads
createDivsForColors(shuffledColors);
```

```css
#game div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 15%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Memory Game!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Memory Game!</h1>
    <div id="game">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
event.target.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myFunction() {
 
  var test = document.getElementById('test');
  test.style.backgroundColor = "green"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.test
{
width: 100px;height:300px;background:red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="test" id="test">testt</div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set background color</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Try this